# How to ignore property of list item in Spring Data Query by Example?

Tags: java, spring-data

I'm trying to create a Spring Data by example query but can't figure out how to properly ignore properties in my example. This is for a MongoRepository if that makes a difference.

Here's the simplified structure of my data objects:

```
@Data
class Person {
 private String name;
 private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Immutable
@Builder
@Getter
class Address {
 @NonNull String country;
 @NonNull StreetAddress streetAddress;
 @Builder.Default(MAIN) AddressType type;
}

@Immutable
@Builder
@Getter
class StreetAddress {
 private @NonNull String street;
 private @NonNull Integer number;
}

enum AddressType {
 MAIN, HOLIDAY;
}
```

I want to be able to query for `name` and `country`. `name` is straightforward and works, but since `Address` is immutable, I do need to set a street. So my query is like this:

```
Person probe = new Person();
probe.setName("Smith");

StreetAddress dummy = StreetAddress.builder().street("").number(-1).build();
Address addressProbe = Address.builder().country("USA").streetAddress(dummy).build();
probe.setAddress(addressProbe);

ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
  .withIgnorePaths("addresses.streetAddress", "addresses.type");

repository.findAll(Example.of(probe, matcher));
```

Now if I leave the `address` field in the person probe `null` (because I don't have a country to search for), the query will find all persons with that name. However, with the address set, I don't retrieve any results.

So I'm assuming my `ignorePaths` are wrong, but I don't find a lot of documentation beyond the trivial case.

First of all, to ignore all the `streetAddress` fields, is it enough to add the `streetAddress` field, or do I need to list all the sub fields? It doesn't make a difference in the result, but since that's wrong anyway, it's not telling me much.

So it seems to come down to the `addresses` being a list? How do I state "ignore these fields in all contained entities" properly? I also tried `addresses.*.streetAddress`.